# how to send email with ionic framework using the native email app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

So I was stuck trying to send email with ionic. I tried many tutorials, examples but nothing worked except this one: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/send-email-android-ios-ionicframework/.

I'm leaving this tutorial here. Please see below for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Very Easy

1. Go to your app root directory
2. Install **Email Composer with Attachments Plugin** type: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer.git`, [link for repo](https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer)
3. Re-build project for your desired platform for example for android: `ionic build android`
4. Now prepare your AngularJS controller:

   ```
   angular.module('myApp').controller('WhatToDoController', function ($scope, $state) {

   var whatToDo = this;

   /**
    * Sends an email using Email composer with attachments plugin and using
    * parameter email.
    *
    * @param email
    */
   whatToDo.sendEmail = function (email) {
     if (window.plugins && window.plugins.emailComposer) { //check if plugin exists

       window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function (result) {
           //console.log("Email sent successfully");
         },

         null,        // Subject
         null,        // Body
         [email],     // To (Email to send)
         null,        // CC
         null,        // BCC
         false,       // isHTML
         null,        // Attachments
         null);       // Attachment Data
     }

   }
   });
   ```
5. Now in your html view you can use the method `sendEmail(email)`:

   ```
   <p>
   Send an email to <a href="#" ng-click="whatToDo.sendEmail('example@email.com')">example@email.com</a>
   </p>
   ```
6. Try to use this on an actual smartphone since in the emulator if you have no configured email app it won't work properly.

If you get stuck or something try: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFfNTdJXVok or https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/send-email-android-ios-ionicframework

Comment: I followed the blog, the function in the library fires the callback is never executed. I can't seem to find the issue. There's no error on console :/

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I use it in my app.js:

```
.controller('EmailCtrl', function($cordovaEmailComposer, $scope) {
$cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
   // is available
   alert("available");
 }, function () {
   // not available
   alert("not available");
 });
 $scope.sendEmail = function(){
  var email = {
     to: 'teste@example.com',
     cc: 'teste@example.com',
     bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
     attachments: [
       'file://img/logo.png',
       'res://icon.png',
       'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
       'file://README.pdf'
     ],
     subject: 'Mail subject',
     body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
     isHtml: true
  };

 $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
   // user cancelled email
  });
 }
});
```

And here in my index.html:

```
<button ng-click="sendEmail()" class="button button-icon icon ion-email">
   Send mail
</button>
```

Comment: Can you tell which plugin you have used for the above answer?